# Span width is not reduced after ellipsis in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have 1 parent `li` element with 2 child `spans` in it.

My first `span` has large title so i applied ellipsis to the parent `li`. 
My issue is when the 1st `span` is ellipsis, The 2nd `span` which should aligned next to it is being place after the full width of 1st `span`.

> To be more clear, 1st span is title and 2nd span is count.

```css
#title {
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
}

#view-count {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<li id="title" title="Documentationxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
  <span>Documentationxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
  <span id="view-count">370</span>
</li>
```

Below is the JSFiddle for it.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayudhandha/ucpaebng/4/)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply `ellipsis` to first `span` and have to remove `position` from second `span`.

Check snippet.

```css
#title {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
}

.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

#view-count {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ff0000;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<li id="title" title="Documentationxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
  <span class="ellipsis">Documentationxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
  <span id="view-count">370</span>
</li>
```

Comment: I want my count (2nd span) to be at the 45 degree angle from the title (1st span). So i need `position: absolute` so that i can move it.

Comment: i have update the answer with position now you place count where ever you want using top and right position. check updated answer.

Comment: glad that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex for this:

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.title > span:nth-child(1) {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #FC0;
}

.title > span:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #CF0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title">
    <span>Documentation documentation documentation documentation documentation documentation</span>
    <span>370</span>
  </li>
  <li class="title">
    <span>Documentation</span>
    <span>370</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer is also good, But i am always preferring to use flex as less as possible as our UI should be supported in IE :(
Thanks btw!